# Merge and return unique array issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, underscore.js

I have an issue with the arrays.

My requirement:
I have an object say

```
data = {
192.168.2.1: ["alpha", "beta", "delta"],
192.168.2.2: ["alpha"],
192.168.2.3: ["delta"],
192.168.2.4: []
}
```

I want to merge all the values (arrays) into one array so that I can read it from UI.

> Desired Output: [alpha, beta, delta]

**Current implementation:**

```
var allControllerList = [];
var uniqueControllerList = [];


   $.each(data, function(i, el){
       allControllerList = allControllerList.concat(el);
   });

   $.each(allControllerList, function(index, el) {
        if($.inArray(el, uniqueControllerList) === -1) uniqueControllerList.push(el);
   });
```

If i want to read it on UI, I need to do this again:

```
            <select id='ssid-list' multiple='multiple'>
              <% _.each(uniqueControllerList, function(ssid, index) { %>
                <option value='<%=controllerIp+ssid%>'>
                    <%=ssid%>
                </option>
              <% }); %>
            </select>
```

I am reading an array three times, I was looking for a more efficient implementation. (Underscore, jQuery or JS).

Thanks,

Comment: What are alpha, beta, delta? Objects or primitive types?

Answer (score 3):

## Using Underscore.js

You can use `_.union`

```js
var data = {
  "192.168.2.1": ["alpha", "beta", "delta"],
  "192.168.2.2": ["alpha"],
  "192.168.2.3": ["delta"],
  "192.168.2.4": []
}

//exctract values from the object
var values = _.values(data);

//use .apply() to give _.union() an array of arrays
var joinedData = _.union.apply(null, values);

console.log(joinedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

## Using vanilla JavaScript

You can simply join everything and then filter for uniqueness. Cross-browser compatible for  IE9 and above (so, no IE8).

```js
var data = {
  "192.168.2.1": ["alpha", "beta", "delta"],
  "192.168.2.2": ["alpha"],
  "192.168.2.3": ["delta"],
  "192.168.2.4": []
}

var seenItems = {};

//Object.values() is not widely supported, otherwise it would have been better
//_.values() can be used instead but this solution is showcasing pure JS
var joinedData = Object.keys(data)
  .reduce(function(memo, key){
    //combine all arrays into one
    return memo.concat(data[key]);
  }, [])
  .filter(function(item) {
    //filter the array by keeping track of what you've seen or not.
    var result = !seenItems[item];

    seenItems[item] = true;
    
    return result;
  });

console.log(joinedData);
```

## Using ES6

Not widely supported in browsers, especially if you want to support something older than current browsers. However, at some point, however, adding it here because of how easy it is.

```js
const data = {
  "192.168.2.1": ["alpha", "beta", "delta"],
  "192.168.2.2": ["alpha"],
  "192.168.2.3": ["delta"],
  "192.168.2.4": []
}

// combine all arrays together
const dupedData = [].concat(...Object.values(data));

//use a Set to remove duplicates and turn it into an array
const deDupedData = Array.from(new Set(dupedData));

console.log(deDupedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this may help

```
let data = {
    '192.168.2.2': ['alpha'],
    '192.168.2.3': ['delta'],
    '192.168.2.4': ['beta'],
    '192.168.2.5': ['alpha']
}

let key = Object.keys(data)

const array = []
for (key in data) {
  if (data[key]) {
    array.push(data[key].toString())
  }
}

console.log(array)
```